# How far away is "nearby"?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes you can see Pokémon "nearby" your location, which is identified by footprint icons depicting the distance that particular Pokémon is from your current location:

[image: Pokémon spotted nearby!]

There are 3 "distances"; 1, 2 or 3 footprints.

How far do each of these represent?